# making one navbar Sticky when user scrolls

Tags: html, css, navbar, nav, sticky

I have two navbars. Let’s say a user navbar on top, and a primary navbar under the user navbar.

I want to have a sticky primary navbar when the user scrolls.

What exactly im trying to do is making the navbars similar to my fav game website header, here https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/
See how the first navbar nicely disappears when you scroll and the second one sticks on top? I really want to have something similar or maybe exactly like this.

```css
#ipsLayout_header header {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(2,25,72,.3);
}
.ipsLayout_container {
    max-width: 1340px;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
.ipsNavBar_primary {
    background: #304d66;
}
```

```html
<div id="ipsLayout_header">
    <header>
        <div class="ipsLayout_container"><!-- my first navbar -->
            <ul id="elUserNav">
                <li id="cCreate">
    links
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>   
    <nav class="ipsLayout_container"><!-- my second navbar -->
        <div class="ipsNavBar_primary">
            <ul class="ipsResponsive_block">
                <li id="elNavSecondary_34">
                links
                </li> 
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code. Make header div fixed to top and on scroll give top minus as much upper-menu height.

css -

```
#ipsLayout_header{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: .3s all 0s ease;
  -moz-transition: .3s all 0s ease;
  transition: .3s all 0s ease;
}
```

js-

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  var headerHeight = $('header').outerHeight();
  if (scroll >= 100) {
    $("#ipsLayout_header").css('top', -headerHeight);
  }
  else {
    $("#ipsLayout_header").css('top', '0');
  }
});
```

JSFiddle -https://jsfiddle.net/dhananjaymane11/wvykLqxb/1/

Comment: Thanks a bunch brother, works perfect. But i have one more question. Im trying to make it similar to this https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/ header that when you scroll down the page you can see the second navbar expands to 100%. I have tried to edit the javascript to add    'if (scroll >= 100) {
    $(".ipsLayout_container").css('max-width', '100%');
  }'    it works but only one time, so when you scroll down it works but when scroll back to top the second navbar still expanded to 100%, since im a newbie with JavaScript and i dont know how to make that work. Any idea?

Comment: I have updated in jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/dhananjaymane11/wvykLqxb/2/ hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, Works perfect :P

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(window).scroll(function(){
   if ($(document).scrollTop()>$('nav').offset().top)
     $('nav').addClass('onTop');
    else 
     $('nav').removeClass('onTop');
  })
})
```

```css
  #ipsLayout_header{
    width:100%;
    height:800px;
    background:#feacbe;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
  }
  #ipsLayout_header header {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        height: 44px;
        background-color: rgba(2,25,72,.3);
    }
    .ipsLayout_container {
        max-width: 1340px;
        padding: 0 15px;
    }
    .ipsNavBar_primary {
      width:100%;
      height:40px;
      background: #304d66;
    }
    .onTop{
      position:fixed;
      z-index:9999;
      width:92%;
      top:0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ipsLayout_header">

 <header>
  <div class="ipsLayout_container"><!-- my first navbar -->
         <ul id="elUserNav">
       <li id="cCreate">
    links
       </li>
         </ul>
     </div>
 </header>
 
 <nav class="ipsLayout_container"><!-- my second navbar -->
  <div class="ipsNavBar_primary">
   <ul class="ipsResponsive_block">
          <li id="elNavSecondary_34">
    links
          </li> 
   </ul>
  </div>
 </nav>

</div>
```

$(document).scrollTop() is the function which is used to get the current scroll position of window, based on that you can change the CSS classes.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  var win = $(window);
  var header = $('#ipsLayout_header');
  var height = $('header').outerHeight(true);
  
  win.on('load scroll', function() {
    if(win.scrollTop() > height) {
      header.addClass('sticky');
      header.css({
        marginTop: -height
      });
    } else {
      header.removeClass('sticky');
      header.css({
        marginTop: 0
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#ipsLayout_header {
  transition: margin 0.25s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#ipsLayout_header header {
  background-color: rgba(2,25,72,.3);
  transform: translateY(0);
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.ipsLayout_container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1340px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.ipsNavBar_primary {
  background: #304d66;
}
.page-content {
  height: 1000px;
}
.ipsResponsive_block,
#elUserNav {margin: 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ipsLayout_header">

  <header>
    <div class="ipsLayout_container"><!-- my first navbar -->
      <ul id="elUserNav">
        <li id="cCreate">
          links
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>

  <nav class="ipsLayout_container"><!-- my second navbar -->
    <div class="ipsNavBar_primary">
      <ul class="ipsResponsive_block">
        <li id="elNavSecondary_34">
          links
        </li> 
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

</div>
<div class="page-content">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<h2>First header</h2>
<header><h1>Sticky Header</h1></header>
<img src="large-image.jpg" width="782" height="2000" alt="Big Image" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){  
    $('header').addClass("sticky");
  }
  else{
    $('header').removeClass("sticky");
  }
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">

    header{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 72px;
  line-height: 108px;
  height: 108px;
  background: #335C7D;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}

.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
</style>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mv0h6r1t/